# Logging try{ ... } catch(e){ ... } using ajax : possible?

Tags: javascript, ajax, exception, logging

When I try the following in the chrome console, i get 'undefined' as the value of 'e':

```
try{
    var test=somethingInvalid();
}
catch(e){
    console.log(e);
}
```

How do I access the details of e?

What properties does it have?

Thanks.

---

Doh. Doing console.log('E is: '+e) seams to work. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it will return `undefined`, because the last line `console.log` doesn't return a value.

```
try{
    false = true;
}
catch(e){
    console.log(e);
}
```

but with the above you will also see an object `> Reference Error` followed by the next line of `undefined`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to MDN, it is the value on the `throw` statement.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

> ### The exception identifier
>
> When an exception is thrown in the try block, `exception_var` (e.g.
>   the `e` in `catch (e)`) holds the value specified by the `throw` statement.
>   You can use this identifier to get information about the exception
>   that was thrown.
>
> This identifier is local to the catch clause. That is, it is created
>   when the catch clause is entered, and after the catch clause finishes
>   executing, the identifier is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, Chrome does output the details of 'e'. I just did this:

```
var err;
try { /* what you did */ }
catch (e) { err = e; }
```

upon which Chrome shows you the details of 'e'.

In this case, you can perform calls to see the contents of the following:

- err.name
- err.arguments
- err.type
- err.stack

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

although all the answers provided were very helpful, what we were infact looking for was:

```
try{
    var test=somethingThatDoesntExist();
}
catch(e){
    console.log(e.message);
}
```

e.message is the variable we want to log, as it (to the best of our knowledge) contains a string representation of the error that was caught.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have a custom `assert()` function that pulls a stack trace of functions (in all modern browsers, except IE):

```
if (!condition) {
    try {
        throw Error();
    } catch (e) {
        // Browsers Firefox, Chrome, Opera provide additional stack property;
        // Check if it does not exist (IE);
        stackTrace = (!e.stack) ? "No stack available" : e.stack;
        self.reportError(errorType, stackTrace, message);
    }
}
```

Obviously, there is a lot more going on than what I'm showing, but the idea is there.